# Get rid of 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've programmed a false 301 redirect in .htaccess

Since it is permanent, my browser/proxy always redirects me to the false address, even if I changed the redirect location address in .htaccess

How can I get rid of this old/false 301 redirect?

Settings things clear: I know how to 301 in .htacces with mod_rewrite. I want to un-301

Comment: Browsers cache 301 redirects locally for each of your URIs so you have to clear your browser's cache manually. However if you want to do this for all of your clients then I guess you will need to tell those browsers to invalidate their cache for all of your affected pages.

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131037/how-to-invalidate-web-browser-cache-content for invalidating browser cache.

Comment: @anubhava: that doesn't help with this case - they are changing the URL of the content - yunzen wants to change the content and keep the URL

Comment: @symcbean Without changing the BASE URI, OP can add a dummy query parameter to force browsers to fetch it again from server.

Comment: @anubhava: this is still changing the URL

Comment: @symcbean: Probably you didn't read my comment carefully :) I just wrote `Without changing the BASE URI`. Of course URL will change with a dummy query parameter which can be ignore in code.

Comment: Symcbean id right. It is a url which is advertised in print. I cannot add a URL parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done in `htaccess` with `mod_redirect` and `mod_header`.

The magic is, that you can set an environtment variable with the `[E]` modifier in Rewrite and set the non cache header if the environtment variabel is set.

Here's the code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mark\.koli\.ch [NC]
## the [E=nocache:1] modifier sets the environment variable "nocache"
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://mark.koli.ch/$1 [R=301,L,E=nocache:1]

## Set the response header if the "nocache" environment variable is set
## in the RewriteRule above.
Header always set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" env=nocache

## Set Expires too ...
Header always set Expires "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" env=nocache
```

Kudos to [Mark S. Kolich](http://mark.koli.ch/) in his [blog entry](http://mark.koli.ch/set-cache-control-and-expires-headers-on-a-redirect-with-mod-rewrite)

Of course this should be done ***before*** the redirect takes place. So after this every 301 redirect is not cached and can be altered with no fuzz.

Maybe it is even possible to set the Environment Variable with PHP via [apache_setenv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-setenv.php).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't depend on your sever configuration since the browser/proxy decides query your webpage or use the cached redirect. You should just clean (or turn off) cache in the browser/proxy you're talking about. If you can't do that, just wait until cache timeout (which depends on the proxy settings) expires.

Comment: What may be the average Time, a proxy will refresh?

Comment: @yunzen No clues. Depends on the settings.